# Mail sending fails through c# when encryption connection is TLS

Tags: c#, asp.net, outlook, smtp

I am setting up mail sending in my code as below

```
    NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailId"].ToString(), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"].ToString());
    MailMessage mm = new MailMessage();
    mm.From = new MailAddress(SendEmailaddress);
    mm.Body = "Test Mail";
    mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
    mm.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
    mm.To.Add(ToEmailAddress);
    mm.Subject = "Test";
    SmtpClient sp = new SmtpClient();
    sp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    sp.Credentials = nc;
    sp.EnableSsl = true;
    sp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    sp.Port = 587
    sp.Host = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMTP"].ToString();
    sp.Send(mm);
```

A error is thrown at the time of mail sending. Mail sending works if I configure outlook on the same PC with these settings with TLS as encrypted connnection.
I have checked many posts where it is suggested that EnableSsl = true should be set for TLS to work but it does not work for me. It throws below error

> Transaction failed. The server response was: 5.7.1
>   : Recipient address rejected: Access denied
>   at System.Net.Mail.RecipientCommand.CheckResponse(SmtpStatusCode
>   statusCode, String response)    at
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.SendMail(MailAddress sender,
>   MailAddressCollection recipients, String deliveryNotify,
>   SmtpFailedRecipientException& exception)    at
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)

I have hit a roadblock as no solution is found. is there a setting which needs to be done on server?

Comment: Port being used is 587.

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void SendAlertEmail(string smtpserver, string smtpport, string smtpuser, string smtppass, int ssl, int auth, string subject, string from, string to, string body)
        {
            try
            {
                MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                mail.From = new MailAddress(SplitEmailStrging(from), HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Request.Form["senderName"]));
                string emails = to;

                if (emails.Contains(","))
                {
                    string[] emailslist = Regex.Split(emails, @",");
                    foreach (string email in emailslist)
                    {
                        mail.To.Add(SplitEmailStrging(email));
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    if (emails.Contains("<"))
                    {

                        mail.To.Add(SplitEmailStrging(emails));
                        // Response.Write(SplitEmailStrging(emails));
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        mail.To.Add(emails);
                        // Response.Write(emails);
                    }

                }

                mail.Subject = subject;
                mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                mail.Body = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(body);
                SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(smtpserver);

                if (int.Parse(smtpport) == 465)
                {
                    client.Port = 25;
                }
                else
                {
                    client.Port = int.Parse(smtpport);
                }

                if (ssl == 1)
                {
                    client.EnableSsl = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    client.EnableSsl = false;
                }

                client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                System.Net.NetworkCredential credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(smtpuser, smtppass);
                client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                client.Credentials = credentials;
                client.Send(mail);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write("Error: " + ex.InnerException.Message);
                Response.End();
            }


        }
```

Comment: I do not see anything you are doing differently.. mail sending code is same as what I am using..